# How do you link XML to a XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Been wondering, just as we use the -declaration to bind XML to a DTD, how do we do it with XSD?

MSDN sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Product ProductID="123" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Product.xsd">
    <ProductName>Rugby jersey</ProductName>
</Product>
```

is it the xsi:NoNamespaceSchemaLocation that does the trick? Or is this just another namespace?

[EDIT]
And is the

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

..line just for giving us a unique XML namespace, or does it also provide information on where the schema can be located?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try  **schemaLocation**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<note
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

noNamespaceSchemaLocation is different.  Note that both are indeed only "hints" in theory, to a consumer of an XML document.  I've never run into an xml processor that did not follow them; after all, it's a W3C recommendation.
see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/

But indeed, it *could* go wrong, as [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-cvs/2007Dec/0043.html), but then again, it's considered a bug for a reason.

To go short : I just trust it, with no harm so far :-)

I don't think any half-decent xml processor can ignore this 'hint' these days.

The urls are always for uniqueness, but in some cases some info will be provided under the URL.

Comment: If you're running in an environment in which access to the Internet is blocked, schemas won't load. Besides, your syntax is wrong. It's namespace<space>location<space>namespace<space>location...

Comment: @Peter It's certainly not from the W3C. w3schools.com has nothing to do with the W3C.

Comment: @John it's just a copy of W3Schools

Comment: @David : true enough I edited id. Although at the time they (I know not for now)  they claimed to be W3C compliant.

Comment: The URI at the top of the answer is no longer valid

Comment: How does the XML processor locate the note.xsd file? Where is that located in relationship to w3schools?

Answer (score 4):

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation and xsi:schemaLocation both provide hints to XML processors who decide to obey those hints. But they are only hints. They do not necessarily cause your document to validate against the schema.

Answer (score 3):

I generally just include the namespace and expect that if whomever is processing it cares to validate it, then they will get the schema and set up their processing environment so that it can find the XSD. I've had limited success with `xsi:schemaLocation` and such attributes. Most of the problems are usually centered around finding the XSD file itself. Some processors want the path to be included which is loads of fun if the XSD is on a file system instead of a web server.

Every processor seems to implement the lookup a little differently. Some use separate schema catalog objects, others require you to load and attach schemas separately. Unless you are providing the code to process documents, you are best off to not include `xsi:schemaLocation` or `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` IMHO. The only thing that their inclusion can do is hamstring whomever is processing your document into either placing the schema in the same location or find some way to make their chosen processor ignore or workaround the location specification.

As a side note, the biggest problem that I've run into was actually with DTDs that were specified using a `SYSTEM` declaration that referred to `"c:\somepath\doc.dtd"`. The problem was that I was processing the documents on a FreeBSD box. I ended up writing my own resolver to map Windows-style paths to a local file system since I could not modify the documents themselves and was required to validate them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a stupid question, but [John Saunders has it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740751/how-do-you-link-xml-to-a-xsd/740758#740758).

> just as we use the -decleration to bind XML to a DTD, how do we do it with XSD?

Here is the essence of the problem - you can't. One of the problems with the DTD approach was that the document specified the validation mechanism and not the document consumer. Post-DTD, you can take an XML document and validate it with XSD or RELAX NG or some other mechanism - they are decoupled (in theory at least). Any XSD link is only a hint and is optional. [It is not possible to validate an arbitrary document](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/java-finding-validation-mechanism-for.html).